# Does LIMIT query make it impossible to make a == condition?

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist, yii, limit

I have a case to code a quiz module which I need to view its question just for 40 questions. Right after the quiz, I have to make `if ..else`condition to decide which input answer is true or not. Because if it is true I will give it a point for each true answer. But it is just can't make it a good condition. It can filter the wrong answers but not the true answers.

I use Yii framework and I think it is nothing to with the Yii script. I think it's the query limit make it complicated. Can anyone help please? I had to complete this for my final project.

Here my database relation:
"soalsoal" is the questions while "jawabanjawaban" is the answers.

[image: Table Relations]

Here's my view for quiz form

```html
<form method="post">

    <?php
        $x = 0;

        foreach ($soal as $data)
        {
            echo $data->soal."<br>";

            $list = CHtml::listData($data->jawabanjawabans, 'idjawab','jawaban');
            echo CHtml::radioButtonList("jawabanku[$x]", '', $list);
            $x++;

            echo "<br><br><hr>";
        }
    ?>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
      <br><br><br><br>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" aria-label="Center">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          Selesai
        </button>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

And here's my quiz page:

```html
<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-info">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
          <strong>Penting!</strong> Isikan masing-masing kolom jawaban dengan benar. <br>
          Jawaban benar akan mendapat poin +4. <br>
          Jawaban salah akan mendapatka poin -1. <br>
          Jawaban kosong akan mendapatkan poin 0. <br>
          Kerjakan dengan baik dan benar. Telitilah dalam membaca soal. Kerjakan <b>hanya soal yang yakin dapat dikerjakan</b>
  </div>

<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1 class="panel-title" >Simulasi</h1>
  </div>  
  <div class="panel-body">

    <?php $this->renderPartial('_form', array('soal'=>$soal)); ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my controller:

```html
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $this->layout='//layouts/column_banksoal';

        date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");

        if (isset($_POST['jawabanku']) ) {
            $model=new Simulasi;
            $jawabanku = $_POST['jawabanku'];
            $model->idsiswa=Yii::app()->user->id;
            $model->idbidang=Yii::app()->user->idbidang;
            $model->date_created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

            $jwbBenar = Soalsoal::model()->findAll(array(
                "select"=>"idjawab",  
                "order"=>"idsoalsoal ASC"));
            $benar = 0; $salah = 0; $kosong = 0; $totalskor=0; $jmlbenar=0; $jmlsalah=0;
            $x = 0;

            foreach ($jwbBenar as $data) { 
                if (!empty($jawabanku[$x])) {
                    if ($data == $jawabanku[$x]) {
                        $benar++;
                    } else if ($jawabanku[$x] == null) {
                        $kosong++;
                    } 
                    $x++;
                }

            }

            $salah     = 40-($benar+$kosong);
            $jmlbenar   = (4*$benar);
            $jmlsalah   = ((-1)*$salah);
            $totalskor  = $jmlbenar + $jmlsalah;
            var_dump($kosong,$totalskor,$jmlbenar,$jmlsalah);

            $model->nilai=$totalskor;
            $model->jml_benar=$benar;
            $model->jml_salah=$salah;
            $model->jml_kosong=$kosong;

            if($model->save())
                {
                    $id=Yii::app()->user->id;

                    $sql="SELECT * FROM simulasi WHERE idsiswa='$id' ORDER BY idsimulasi ASC";

                    $dataProvider=new CSqlDataProvider($sql,array(
                        'keyField' => 'idsimulasi',
                    ));

                    $this->render('hasil', array(
                        'model'=>$model,
                        'benar'=>$benar, 
                        'kosong'=>$kosong, 
                        'salah'=>$salah, 
                        'totalskor'=>$totalskor,
                        'grafikskor'=>$dataProvider,));
                }


        } else {
            $idbidang=Yii::app()->user->idbidang;
            $soal = Soalsoal::model()->findAll(array(
                "select"=>"idsoalsoal,soal,idbidang,gambar,kunci,idjawab", 
                "condition"=>"idbidang=$idbidang", 
                "order"=>"rand() LIMIT 40"));

            $this->render('create', array('soal'=>$soal));

        }

    }
```

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience. :(
i forgot to make it not caps lock.

Comment: sory for my bad english too. Instead if you know the answer please help :)